# How to parse JSON using DOJO AJAX and REST

Tags: ajax, json, rest, dojo

I am trying to send a request to a REST server using DOJO AJAX, however I get a null object as result (console):

You CLICKED = click clientX=34, clientY=13
JSON loaded from server: null

Here is my code:

```
// JavaScript Document

// load requirements for declarative widgets in page content
require([   "dojo/parser",
        "dojo/dom",
        "dojo/domReady!",
        "dijit/form/Button"
        ]);


// Start initializing
dojo.ready(function(){

dojo.connect (
                aBut1,
                "onClick",
                function(e){

                    console.log('You CLICKED = ', e);
                    dojo.xhrGet({
                                // The URL of the request
                                url: "http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Specialty/ESRI_StatesCitiesRivers_USA/MapServer/find",
                                // Handle the result as JSON data
                                handleAs: "json",
                                // content
                                content: {f:"json", searchText:"new", contains:"true", searchFields:"state_new", layers:"2", returnGeometry:"false" },
                                // The success handler
                                load: function(jsonData) {
                                    // Create a local var to append content to
                                    console.info("JSON loaded from server:  ", jsonData);

                                },
                                // The error handler
                                error: function() {
                                    console.log('JSON log Error');
                                }
                            });

                });


}); // End dojo.ready
```

This is the REST url I would like to use:

http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Specialty/ESRI_StatesCitiesRivers_USA/MapServer/find?searchText=new&contains=true&searchFields=state_name&sr=&layers=2&returnGeometry=false&f=json

I save the result of this URL in a json file and AJAX works reading that file and returning an object with 4 items. It is not using REST URL.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are trying to use dojo.xhrGet to access a different domain, which it cannot do.

> Limitations
>
> dojo.xhrGet (and other functions in the same line: dojo.xhrPost,
>   dojo.xhrDelete, dojo.xhrPut), are bound by the ‘same domain’ security
>   policy of the browser. This means that they can only establish a
>   connection back to the same server that served the HTML page. If you
>   wish to use this API to talk to servers other than the one that
>   originated your page, then you will have to use a proxy on your
>   originating server and have it forward the requests. The only other
>   solution to working around the same domain restriction is to use
>   alternate IO methods, such as dojo.io.script.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/xhrGet.html

Answer (score 0):

That's not much to go on. What happens if you use `curl` to make a request to that URL?

Are you using Dojo 1.7? If so, maybe the [Ajax Quickstart docs](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/quickstart/ajax.html#dojo-1-7-amd) can help (I linked directly to the AMD-style, since that's probably what you should be using if you can). There are also more detailed [docs on `xhrGet`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/xhrGet.html#dojo-xhrget).